# Multi output neural network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

I am trying to create a neural network that outputs more than a binary value.
The problem is the following:
I have recently stumbled upon this problem on kaggle https://www.kaggle.com/c/poker-rule-induction
Basically, the problem is getting the program to predict the hands the test set has to classify it from 0-9. I have already managed to solve this problem using RandomForest library.
My question is how can I solve this problem using a neural network?
I have already tried to follow some tutorials where you have 2 binary inputs and 1 binary output.
Dataset looks like the following:
[image]

Comment: are you confused about how to structure your outputs because there are multiple?

Comment: yes, that is proving to be a problem. I am new to neural networks and I tried some examples but with binary values either 1 or 0, i did not manage to find something similar to my problem.

Comment: The data doesn't really suit NN. It's too small. In general, to produce N outputs, you'll just have the last layer with N neurons with the required activation function applied. For this specific case, I'd use the SOFTMAX activation as it will give you the probability of each hand, and the sum of probabilites of all N neurons in the last layer will be 1.0.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you are asking how to structure your neural network output neurons for binary classification. Instead of having one value that outputs a non-binary (0-9) which doesn't really work for many reasons, you can design the outputs to produce a binary vector.

Where...

1 = [0,**1**,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

2 = [0,0,**1**,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

3 = [0,0,0,**1**,0,0,0,0,0,0]

...etc

So, each item in the vector can be one of the 10 output neurons, and if that item is a 1, its position refers to its classification group. The best example of this, is the  MNIST digit neural networks that also usually 10 neuron binary outputs.

Bare in mind the actual outputs will be decimals representing a probability / guess, that is close to either 0, or the 1.

This also means your target value has to be a vector that back propagates each item that corresponds to each neuron.